# Kusto Query Language: How to save column of results into a variable?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Lets say I have a query like:

```
cluster("cluster1").database("db2").Table3
| distinct *  // distinct combinations of data
| take 5  // take 5
```

How do I save the values from a column in the results output to a `pack_array` variable.
I want to use this `pack_array` variable for follow on queries like:

```
cluster("cluster2").database("db3").Table1
| where ColumnofInterest in (pack_array_var from above)
| take 5  // take 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide the "*" argument to the function and use the "let" statement. Here is an example:

```
let ValuesFromTheOtherCluster = cluster('cluster1').database('db2').Table3
| extend tempArray = pack_array(*)
| summarize filters = make_set(tempArray); 
cluster('cluster2').database("db3").Table1
| where ColumnofInterest in (ValuesFromTheOtherCluster)
```

Comment: This is helpful -- but how can I use this saved data *across* queries. Note in the example I am interested in data on `cluster1`, `database2`; yet I want to use those results to inform my search on `cluster2`, `database3`

Comment: aha I see, I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This is great!!